# HTML parser for GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, html-parsing, lxml

Generally I use [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) for my HTML parsing needs, but that isn't available on Google App Engine. The obvious alternative is [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), but I find it chokes too easily on malformed HTML. Currently I am testing [libxml2dom](http://www.boddie.org.uk/python/HTML.html) and have been getting better results.

Which pure Python HTML parser have you found performs best? My priority is the ability to handle bad HTML over speed.

Comment: Doh! libxml2 is not included in the Python on GAE so libxml2dom is out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No longer a problem - lxml is supported:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Comment: is it available in GAE? or I have to include by myself.

Answer (score 5):

From the [BeautifulSoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/3.1-problems.html):

> Version 3.1.0 of Beautiful Soup does significantly worse on real-world HTML than version 3.0.8 does

So, it might help you to use this earlier version. That is precisely what the author himself recommends.

> You can pretend that Beautiful Soup version 3.1.0 was never released. Version 3.0.8 still works fine on Python 2.3 through 2.6.

Comment: Thanks for that - I got better performance with 3.0.8 but it still failed to parse the webpage usefully.
Also the BS author has lost interest in developing it further so I had better invest time elsewhere.